# Techniques to solve an "equivalence" of 3 variables given some function?

Tags: functions, fixed-point-theorems

Given a function $f$ and that $$f(x) = y, f(y) = z, f(z) = x$$ how would I find all possible triples $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy that system. I am not interested in any examplesbut general technques for this problem.

Comment: You simply have to find a fixed point of $f \circ f \circ f$ with the usual methods.

Comment: adding to Crostul's comment, if you want distinct $x,y,z$, then you also need to be careful about fixed points of $f$.